# How to search multiple fields in ng-select?

Tags: angular6, angular5, angular7, angular-ngselect

I want to merge two API fields "**code and name**" in ng-select dropdown. 
For example:-

```
  Code       : MI

  name       : MI 3sPrime

 Format      : MI - MI 3sPrime
```

I used the below code for dropdown

**Component.Html**

```
<ng-select [items]="products" bindLabel="code" bindValue="id"
                placeholder="Select Goods Receipt" clearAllText="Clear" formControlName="productId" [searchFn]="customSearchFn">

                  <ng-template ng-label-tmp let-item="item">
                    <span [ngOptionHighlight]="search">{{ item.code }} - {{ item.name }}</span>
                  </ng-template>

                  <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item" let-search="searchTerm" let-index="index">
                    <span [ngOptionHighlight]="search">{{ item.code }} - {{ item.name }}</span>
                  </ng-template>

</ng-select>
```

**Component.ts**

```
  customSearchFn(term: string, item: any) {
    term = term.toLocaleLowerCase();
    return item.code.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(term) > -1 || 
    item.name.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(term) > -1;
 }
```

**Searching:** Code and name  is fetching while searching. But I want to search for code , name and given format(Code - name)

Below are the diagrams

[image]

Here, While I search the **"MI -"** , Searching not works

[image]

Searching should apply for the format **code - name**..Which means when I type **MI -**, filteration have to work. 
Is there any method? Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this

```
  customSearchFn(term: string, item: any) {
    term = term.toLocaleLowerCase();
    return item.code.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(term) > -1 || 
    item.name.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(term) > -1 || 
    (item.code + " - " + item.name).toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(term) > -1;
 }
```

Comment: Use an arrow function if you want "this" to be defined.

`customSearchFn = (term: string, item: any) => {
  // Can use this.something here
}`

Comment: at html -> <ng-select [searchFn]="customSearchFn">